# Pulseaudio setting in debian

Tags: audio, debian, pulseaudio

I am using Debian 7 wheezy(64 bit) in dell inspiron i5. Default audio driver in pulseaudio and other two are HDA Intel and HDA ATI HDMI .

So here is the question when increase or decrease volume from any player like vlc,movie player volume increase in pulseaudio but it also make the speaker and PCM volume 100% in HDA Intel driver which make my speaker mad and gives very odd sound. I check it from alsamixer

This is three driver default pulseaudio
[image]

I change the driver to hda intel and this is what i set in hda Intel Driver 
[image]

I change driver back to pulseaudio and increase or decrease volume from any player or system volume, here is the setting of hda Intel Driver again speaker and PCM 100% 
[image]

So my problem is, i dont want that setting of hda driver to be changed if i increase or decrease volume.